# Space character added to end of zsh prompt in profile is being ignored. How can I add spacing?

Tags: shell, zsh, iterm2

Context:

- I am using iterm2
- my profile is set to `~/.zshrc`
- my current prompt is set with the following in my profile `export PS1=$'%d ~  # \40'`

Other prompt values that did not return the desired behaviour:

```
export PS1=$'%d ~  # \32'
export PS1=$'%d ~  # \160'
export PS1=$'%d ~  #  '
```

My current prompt looks like this:

```bsh
user #
```

When I type something, the text appears directly next to the prompt:

```
user #echo 'test'
```

I am attempting to achieve the following behavior (?)/layout with the prompt:

```
user# echo 'test'
```

Where there is a space between my code and the prompt.

Why isn't the space displaying?

Additional context:
I am using a MBP with an M1 chip.

Update: per @Jeff Schaller's suggestion I have tried `PS1=$'%d ~ <0001f370> # '` which also did not work

Comment: I'm curious why a plain old space didn't work; something like `PS1=$'%d ~ <0001f370> # '`

Comment: Tried this just now and that didn't work either -- updating post.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your `export PS1=$'%d ~  #  '` and it worked the way you want, with the space. I’m using the kitty terminal on Debian. I suspect `iterm2` is doing something weird.

Comment: I have another (older) macbook that this works fine on -- could the difference could be related to iterm or the chip?